# copy some columns from a data sets and paste in other in unix

Tags: unix

I want to copy some column (c2 and c3) from a data set (A), and past in data set B. Here is the data look like:

A

```
c1 c2 c3
3  2  9
5  3  2
9  1  1
```

B

```
c1 c2
1  2
1  9
1  6
```

Desired data should be:

```
c1 c2 c3 c4
1  2  2  9
1  9  3  2
1  6  1  1
```

probably it's basic stuff, but i am pretty new with unxi, any help please?

Answer (score 0):

You could use command [paste](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paste_(Unix)) and [awk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK), for example:

```
paste b a | awk '{print $1, $2, $4, $5}'
```